# Kickstart file not being found in VituralBox

Tags: rhel, iso, kickstart

[image]I am installing a STIG RHEL on a virtual box and therefore have a custom kick start file in the iso I am using. The iso structure looks like this for the kickstart file

```
ROOT
|
|----stig_fix
         |
         |----stig_fix.cfg
```

However, when I try to install using the iso image from the storage option in vituralbox, it keeps saying it can not find the kickstart file. Does anyone know what value I should make ks equal to in the main menu, to get vitural box to be able to find the kickstart file?

Comment: Could you see if `ks=file:/stig_fix/stig_fix.cfg` works?

Comment: I get an "Error opening kickstart file /stig_fix/stig_fix.cfg: No such file or directory". I have however extracted the iso and saw that the file does exist and is filled in correctly in the iso image.

Comment: How about trying `linux text ks=cdrom:/stig_fix/stig_fix.cfg` from the `boot:` prompt?

Comment: nope didn't work either. Whenever I try to install manually after it fails to find the kickstart file, it says that no disk can be found in the cd-rom drive. Maybe this has something to do with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error was with how I was building the iso. The tar ball I was trying to put in the iso was corrupt. I re-downloaded the tar ball and now the kickstart file works correctly.